# How to get stock quantity of each product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity

How to get stock quantity of each product in list.phtml in Magento 2 ?

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-product-available-qty-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Solution:1**

Create Helper file **Stock.php** in your module

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper;

class Stock extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface
     */
    protected $stockState;

    /**
     * Output constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
    ) {
        $this->stockState = $stockState;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve stock qty whether product
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @param int $websiteId
     * @return float
     */
    public function getStockQty($productId, $websiteId = null)
    {
        return $this->stockState->getStockQty($productId, $websiteId);
    }
}
```

**After add bellow code in your list.phtml file**

```
$websiteId = 1;  // Current websiteId
$productId = 2; // $_product->getId()  Product Id
$_helperStock = $this->helper({VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Stock::class);
echo $_helperStock->getStockQty($productId, $websiteId);
```

**Solution:2**

Add bellow code in your `list.phtml` file

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
   $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
   print_r($stockItem->getQty()); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank for your help ! I think I need to call out function getQty() not getMinimalQty(). But in module catalog doesn't have that function. What should I do ?

Comment: Updates ans pls check now

Comment: For some reason, running this in a cron job always returns '0'

Comment: In M2.1.1 I only get: ``Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /private/var/www/[project]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 126
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /private/var/www/[project]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 126``

Comment: Don't forget to flush the var/cache and var/generation after your changes.

Comment: @Abdul What about for configurable products?

Comment: Use of `getInstance()` should be discouraged. You should use the constructor method instead (see Surendra Kumar Ahir's solution).

Comment: Please use DI instead of ObjectManager directly!

Comment: Never use code like this directly. Use constructor DI instead.

Comment: `StockStateInterface` is deprecated.

Comment: @WackGet https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html - "Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class. See usage rules."

Standards are there for a reason, developers should respect that.

Comment: @Tisch There are plenty of cases where using ObjectManager directly is fine. Standalone scripts, product feeds, cron jobs, etc.; all fine. From your own link, Magento states: "In a global scope, like in fixtures of integration tests, you can use the object manager." Don't just blindy parrot stuff when the reality is far more nuanced.

Comment: things have changed in the meantime \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface is @deprecated - 100.3.0 Replaced with Multi Source Inventory

Answer (score 26):

Like some comments have mentioned, you want to use dependency injection. Do not use the object manager; in other words, do not do what any of the other responses state. The following technique can be applied anywhere. For Blocks, set the class to your class in layout XML, which extends the original, and inject the right information.

Inject the `StockRegistryInterface` interface where you need access:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
private $stockRegistry;

/**
 * Constructor for DI.
 *
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

/**
 * Get the product stock data and methods.
 *
 * @return \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
public function getStockRegistry()
{
    return $this->stockRegistry;
}
```

To use it somewhere:

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry */
$stockRegistry = [$this|$block]->getStockRegistry();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = [Grab Product instance however you want. This is up to you.]

// Get stock data for given product.
$productStock = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());

// Get quantity of product.
$productQty = $productStock->getQty();
```

For reference, Magento2 uses this exact interface all over the catalog when it comes to retrieving product stock information.

Note that anything within square brackets needs to be modified.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Although I haven't tested it (yet) it follows conventions.

Comment: I've tested it, and this is the correct way to do this. using the object manager is a no-no.

Comment: Allways +1 for best practices!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as StockRegistryInterface works on every case, not the StockStateInterface.

Comment: just a note that going forward StockRegistryInterface won't be a viable option as it is implementing \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface which is @deprecated 100.3.0 Replaced with Multi Source Inventory

Comment: We tried using 

$productStock = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());

But it turns out that you actually can't (easily) get a stockItem by a product id. Instead you need to get the stockitem's id to fetch the complete stock item from the stockItem repository.
Using the above code will result in getting the wrong stock item as in the`cataloginventory_stock_item` table you can see these are different id's.

Answer (score 12):

**How to get stock quantity of each product in Magento 2**

for controller or block inject  \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
   )
  {
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
  }
```

and then use getStockQty function to get qty

```
 $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

if you want to get quantity in .phtml file then use

```
 <?php 
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
 echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

Comment: returning qty 0 for me even though i have qty 30

Comment: @jafarpinjar found out today this also factors status - if disabled returns 0 - I can't decide if this is a good thing or not...

Answer (score 7):

The below script will be helpful to get the product stock qty, min qty and stock details in magento2.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
print_r($productStockObj->getData());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `$productobj` after saving product from backend side so you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Right now you have to need develop new module for M2

Then Create this `events.xml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Create your observer file `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId(); //Get Product Id

        //Get Quantity
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockData = $stockItem->getQty();
        // Get new Qty
        $_vendor_qty = $product->getVendorQty();
        $_on_hand_qty = $product->getOnHandQty();
        $totalQty = $_vendor_qty+$_on_hand_qty; //Add New Qty


        $stockItem->setQty($totalQty); //Set New Qty to Main Qty
        $stockItem->save();

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the product object and do not want to use the other classes, You can try in the following way.

```
// For phtml file
$prodObj = $_product->load($_product->getId()); // $_product object in list.phtml
$stockItem = $prodObj->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$stockQty = $stockItem->getQty(); // $stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();

// For php class file
$stockItem = $prodObj->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
$stockQty = $stockItem->getQty(); // $stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Registry and \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\ classes are deprecated. So you can use helper class in Magento\Catelog

```
 <?php


namespace Package\ModuleName\Block;


use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


class StockLeft extends Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
     */
    private Data $helper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository
     */
    private \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository;


    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data=[],
        Data $helper,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }//end __construct()


    public function getRemaining()
    {
        return $this->stockItemRepository->get($this->helper->getProduct()->getId())->getQty();

    }//end getRemaining()


}//end class
```

To get salable Qty you can use \Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku

```
public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data=[],
        Data $helper,
        \Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->helper              = $helper;
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }//end __construct()


    public function getRemaining()
    {
        $salableQty = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($this->helper->getProduct()->getSku());
        return $salableQty[0]['qty'];

    }//end getRemaining()
```