# Get stock for a product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, stock

I want to display the current stock of a specific product in a theme. How can I do that?

`getStock()` does not seem to work.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97952/36463

Comment: Object Manager shouldn't really be used..

Comment: not a big deal! change to dependency injection method, I share this link just for idea :-)

Answer (score 6):

It mainly depends on the file where you want to display it.

First you need to **find out the block where you want to display that info.**

Then you'll have to **setup a preference for that block in a custom module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Path\To\Core\Block\You\Want\To\Rewrite" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom" />
</config>
```

Then create your `Block\Custom` file:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Custom extends Path\To\Core\Block\You\Want\To\Rewrite
{
    protected $_stockRegistry;

    public function _construct(
         ...
         \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
         ...)
     {
         $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
         ...
     }

     public function getStockItem($productId)
     {
         return $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
     }
}
```

> Please note the `...` in the constructor. You'll have to replace those
>   with the original arguments from the block you're rewriting and then
>   call the parent constructor with the original parameters.

Finally in your template you can do:

```
$stockItem = $block->getStockItem($productId);
$stockQty = $stockItem->getQty();
```

Comment: is there any possibility by receiving this values WITHOUT creating a new module?

Comment: @Max yes using the ObjectManager directly but that's not recommended

Comment: And that is the only possibility? Always asked myself if there is a way more simple then doing so (creating a plugin)

Comment: @Max well there's two possibilities : object manager (not recommended) or module (recommended)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism  .. I need to display Quantity in grouped product. Can you please look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/153914/29175

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function to get stock Qty

```
protected $stockStateInterface;

    public function _construct(
         ...
         \\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockStateInterface,
         ...)
     {
         $this->stockStateInterface = $stockStateInterface;
         ...
     }

     public function getStockItemQty($product)
     {
         return $this->stockStateInterface->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
     }

     //return true if product in stock otherwise return false
      public function getStockItemStatus($product)
      {
        return $this->stockStateInterface->verifyStock($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
      }
```

Comment: Hi, I can't edit your post. Where is the `$this->_stockItemRepository` come from? It should be `$this->stockStateInterface`.