# Display Stock Quantity on grouped product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, quantity

I need to display **Stock Quantity on grouped products**.

Grouped product detail are displaying by `grouped.phtml`

**(Core module: module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml)**.

I have extended this module and i need to display **Quantity** there.

***Update:*** This is foreach loop that display products and I need to display Stock qty in for-each loop.

I am not sure If i can display from function reference of stock.

Line 34 - 82:

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')); ?>" class="col item">
                <strong class="product-item-name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" class="col qty">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input type="number" name="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           data-selector="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           maxlength="12"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                           data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
            && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
            && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $_item,
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
            ))): ?>
            <tr class="row-tier-price">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?php echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                        $_item,
                        \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                    ) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: please show your code, which you have tried.

Comment: @Rakesh Sir  ,   Code is of default magento 2.1.2 : Root/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/tem‌​plates/product/view/‌​type/grouped.phtml and Updated question with code.

Comment: @Jai : is it know about discount for grouped products,

Comment: @JeevaRathinam    Please elaborate

Comment: @Jai : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152608/products-type-grouped-product-how-can-i-create-discount-for-grouped-product

Comment: @jai : i just want to add discount for grouped products, in my grouped products 3 products, front end display normal price, after add to cart the price should be discount 15 %

Comment: @Jai : i hope so you understand my requirement

Comment: yes and discount is possible with grouped products. Please consider this case  [1] 0-10 :$20 for each [2] 11-22 : $15 for each  .  Do you need something like this?

Comment: I think you need something like this site used: http://www.mitrelinen.com/products/savoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51591/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-jai).

Comment: Are you looking for simple product qty?

Comment: no, could u pls join chat

Comment: @Jai    http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51591/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-jai

Comment: @Jai, Are you looking for simple product qty?

Comment: @Rakesh Sir..is it possible to display quantity of product there?  Pls check if you have some time and I think i can sort out what Jeeva require.

Comment: @Jai Have you check for grouped product qty issue?

Comment: not yet Sir. I just finished my issue with your answer. Accepted your answer and upvoted. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just create block file keep below code in block file,

**app/code/Vendor/Extra/Block/Grouped.php file,**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extra\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;

class Grouped extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,          
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = [] 
    ){      
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);    
    }

    public function getProductQty($id){
        if(is_numeric($id)){           
            $product = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($id);            
            return $product->getQty();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml**

Inside foreach loop in above file,

```
<?php 
    $blocks = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Extra\Block\Grouped');
    foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item):
        echo $qtys = $blocks->getProductQty($_item->getId());
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. public function get($stockItemId) - This returns the id in the stock table, but not the product_id