# Magento 2 get and set Qty of product with observer

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I tried my code below to get Qty from observer when a page loaded :

Observer :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $collections = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
        var_dump($collection->getQty());
    }
}
```

events.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
    <observer name="loadupdates" instance="Test\Show\Observer\CustomPrice" />
  </event>
</config>
```

But, i got all NULL for getQty of products. So my question, how can i get the Qty of products, and how to update the Qty from the observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get Inventory of the product, you should inject `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface` first. Then using `getStockQty` to get the qty of an product. So that in your observer:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
)
{
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $collections = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
        var_dump($this->stockItem->getStockQty($collection->getId()));
    }
}
```

Ref: [How to get stock quantity of each product in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2)

Comment: omg i forget to add the injection, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `$productobj` after saving product from backend side so you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Right now you have to need develop new module for M2

Then Create this `events.xml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Create your observer file `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId(); //Get Product Id

        //Get Quantity
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockData = $stockItem->getQty();
        // Get new Qty
        $_vendor_qty = $product->getVendorQty();
        $_on_hand_qty = $product->getOnHandQty();
        $totalQty = $_vendor_qty+$_on_hand_qty; //Add New Qty


        $stockItem->setQty($totalQty); //Set New Qty to Main Qty
        $stockItem->save();

    }   
}
```