# Magento 2 Unable To Get Simple Product Quantity

Tags: simple-product, magento-2.1.7, quantity

I am unable to get simple product's quantity 
Can anyone help out please.

I have tried:

```
$product = $block->getAllowProducts();

foreach ($product  as $child) {
    print_r($child->getQty());
    print_r($child);
}
```

`$child->getQty()` returns nothing and it doesn't seem to be in  `$child` array either

```
Array
(
  [entity_id] => 1
  [attribute_set_id] => 4
  [type_id] => simple
  [sku] => t-shirt-red
  [has_options] => 0
  [required_options] => 0
  [created_at] => 2017-10-24 10:05:40
  [updated_at] => 2017-10-24 10:05:40
  [parent_id] => 4
  [catalog_rule_price] => 
  [name] => t-shirt-red
  [url_key] => t-shirt-red
  [price] => 99.9900
  [weight] => 100.0000
  [color] => 4
  [status] => 1
  [tax_class_id] => 2
  [is_featured] => 1
  [media_gallery] => Array
    (
      [images] => Array
        (
        )

      [values] => Array
         (
         )

    )

[tier_price] => Array
    (
    )

[salable] => 1
)
```

Any help please, appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look in to the below post,
  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2/97952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant get directly product quantity. You need to call `StockStateInterface` to get qty of product.

For get qty based on product id,

```
public function __construct(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState)
{        
    $this->stockState = $stockState;
}

public function getOptionsQty($currentProduct, $allowedProducts)
{
    $product = $block->getAllowProducts();

    foreach ($product  as $child) {
        $productId = $child->getId();
        $qty = $this->stockState->getStockQty($productId,1);          
        echo $qty;
        print_r($child);
    }
}
```

**Using directly objectmanager,**

```
$product = $block->getAllowProducts();

    foreach ($product  as $child) {
        $productId = $child->getId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $stockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
        $qty = $stockState->getStockQty($productId,1);
        echo $qty;
        print_r($child);
    }
```

Comment: @Rakesk It works But I wasn't planing on using ObjectManager! I was more looking into something like this: `$child->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty()` but it returns `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the qty.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description'))
     ->joinField('qty',
                 'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                 'qty',
                 'product_id=entity_id',
                 '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                 'left');


foreach ($products as $product) {
  $p['products'][] = array(
        'id'        => $product->getId(),
        'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
        'name'      => $product->getName(),
    'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
      'weight'      => $product->getWeight(),
    'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
        'pirce'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,

     //get qty
     'qty'          => $product->getQty(),
     );
 }
```

Comment: @ Vivek , Your solution is in Magento-1, but the required solution should be in Magento-2.

Comment: Oh yes, that is for magento1, but you can use it in magento2 by changing some of its functions which are changed in M2

Comment: this worked for me in magento 1