# display stock information to logged customer only in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, stock-status

I want to display stock only to logged customers in product page. can you guide me how can I do and in which file?

Comment: Do you want to show In stock/Out of stock message or available quantity as well?

Comment: Available qty as well

Comment: Use code of this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2/143905

Comment: How do you manage the configruable stock qty?

Comment: i don't have configurable products.

Comment: Thanks Ansar! but I want to display qty only for logged customer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add condition to check if customer is logged in or not. There are multiple ways either do with object manager in template or create a module / block which will return if customer is available or not . you can check this post [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2) to know how to implement that check.

**Method 1 :**

now create a template file **customer-qty.phtml** in /app/design/frontend/package-name/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customer-qty.phtml

and add code blow :

```
/**
* Product view template
*
* @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Customer-qty
*/
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
?>   

<div id="get-customer-qty">        
    <?php echo $product->getQty(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?

Andd then add this template block in your **catalog_product_view.xml** layout file :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customer.qty" as="customerQty" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/customer-qty.phtml" group="detailed_info"/>
```

**Method 2 is :**

copy `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml`

and paste in you theme folder ( like that ):
`/frontend/package-name/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml`

And update file with below code :

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
   if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

   ?>
   <?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView  */?>
   <?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>



    <?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <div class="stock available" style="display: none" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="stock unavailable" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
        <span style="background: red; color: #fff; padding: 2px 10px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px; padding : 5px 15px"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Sold Out') ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div><?php echo $_product->getQty(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php }?>
```

**NOTE :** for configurable products same you have to do with Configurable product template.

Again, i have used object manager for quick implementation and understanding however you can create a module and block for this which is more systematic way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried this code but it's not working

Comment: update your question with code you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, it will hide stock sku information from the product details page for not logged in user.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_layout_handles" instance="Anshu\Custom\Observer\AddHandles" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Observer/AddHandles.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(CustomerSession $_customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $_customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This will give you some idea and you can modify it according to your requirement.