# M2: How to get total stock qty

Tags: magento2

I will try get total stock product qty.

I use this below code:

```
    <?php
echo "Total qty: ";
?>
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($productId);
?>
```

But script display 0 qty for all products.

Here is full file code:

```
<?php
$_helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$options = $_product->getOptions();
$matrix = $this->getPriceMatrix(2);
/*
 * border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
 */
?>
<?php if ($matrix && is_array($matrix)) : ?>
       <h4 class="product name product-item-name">
                                                <?php 
                            $optionText = '';
                            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mgs_brand');
                            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getMgsBrand());
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                            <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                            </h4><br />
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($matrix as $r => $variant) : ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo ($r % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
                <td style="text-align:left;width:50%">
                    <?php $i = 0;
                    foreach ($variant['attributes'] as $attribute => $variants) :$i++ ?>
                        <?php if ($i > 1) : ?><br/><?php endif; ?>
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $attribute; ?><span>: </span></span>
                        <span class="data"><?php $idx = 0;
                            foreach ($variants as $name => $tmp) : ?><?php echo $idx++ ? ',' : ''; ?><?php echo $name; ?><?php endforeach; ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;width:30%">
                    <div class="bl-price-variants"><?php echo $variant['price_formated']; ?></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
echo "Total qty: ";
?>
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($productId);
?>
    <hr />
<?php endif; ?>
```

update2:

I created file in: `app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Block/stockleft.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Devidas
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 */
namespace Snmportal\Publication\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
/**
 * Class StockLeft
 */
class StockLeft extends Template
{
    /** @var Registry  */
    private $_registry;

    /** @var Product  */
    private $_Product;

    /** @var session  */
    private $session;

    /** @var session  */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * StockLeft constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Product $product
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        Product $product,
        SessionManagerInterface $session,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_Product = $product;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRemainingQty() {
        $productId = $this->getCurrentProduct();
        $stock = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
        return $stock->getQty();
    }

    /**
     * @return Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected function getCurrentProduct() {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
    }


}
```

Next I add code to:  `app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml`

```
<?php 
/**
 * @copyright Devidas
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 *
 *@var Snmportal\Publication\Block\StockLeft $block
 **/
$RemainingQty = $block->getRemainingQty();

?>
<?php
$_helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$options = $_product->getOptions();
$matrix = $this->getPriceMatrix(2);
/*
 * border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
 */
?>
<?php if ($matrix && is_array($matrix)) : ?>
       <h4 class="product name product-item-name">
                                                <?php 
                            $optionText = '';
                            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mgs_brand');
                            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getMgsBrand());
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                            <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                            </h4><br />
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($matrix as $r => $variant) : ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo ($r % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
                <td style="text-align:left;width:50%">
                    <?php $i = 0;
                    foreach ($variant['attributes'] as $attribute => $variants) :$i++ ?>
                        <?php if ($i > 1) : ?><br/><?php endif; ?>
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $attribute; ?><span>: </span></span>
                        <span class="data"><?php $idx = 0;
                            foreach ($variants as $name => $tmp) : ?><?php echo $idx++ ? ',' : ''; ?><?php echo $name; ?><?php endforeach; ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;width:30%">
                    <div class="bl-price-variants"><?php echo $variant['price_formated']; ?></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Qty Available: <?php echo $RemainingQty; ?></p>
    <hr />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now When I try generate catalog pdf then get issue:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRemainingQty() on null in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/snmpdf5e4fd692cebde3.63866984.php(2): include() #1 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Block/Generator.php(327): include('/home/user/d...') #2 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Block/Generator.php(344): Snmportal\Publication\Block\Generator->renderSource('<?php\r\ninclude ...') #3 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Block/Generator.php(303): Snmportal\Publication\Block\Generator->fetchView('dummy') #4 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Snmportal\Publication\Block\Generator->_toHtml() #5 /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Helper/Data in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml on line 9
```

Comment: Hello @Sylvester Please follow this links :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2

Comment: the issue is your product id not pass to getCurrentProduct()

Comment: Do you now how to solve?

Comment: yes wait for a min I will update my code

Comment: First, get product id in your template file. I just get product id using getProductId() function. then replace 2 line below code in your template file   $productId = $this->getProductId();
$RemainingQty = $block->getRemainingQty($productId);

Comment: and replace the below function getRemainingQty($productId) {
        $stock = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
        return $stock->getQty();
    }

Comment: Thank you. But It got a bit mixed up. Can you please edit your answer and make these changes directly on  our codes?

Then we can accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer if it's working for u then accept it\

Comment: I update your code but still we get issue: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRemainingQty() on null in /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml:10 Stack trace: #0

Comment: First get product Id in your template file then pass to getRemainingQty() method

Comment: Debug product Id print or not in your template

Comment: Can you please provide me more information how can I do it? "Debug product Id print or not in your template"

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

create a block for the business logic of template  `Custom\Modulestock\Block\StockLeft.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Devidas
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 */
namespace Custom\Modulestock\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
/**
 * Class StockLeft
 */
class StockLeft extends Template
{
    /** @var Registry  */
    private $_registry;

    /** @var Product  */
    private $_Product;

    /** @var session  */
    private $session;

    /** @var session  */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * StockLeft constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Product $product
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        Product $product,
        SessionManagerInterface $session,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_Product = $product;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRemainingQty($productId) {
    $stock = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
    return $stock->getQty();
}

    /**
     * @return Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected function getCurrentProduct() {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
    }


}
```

Template file

> Custom/Modulestock/view/frontend/templates/stock_left.phtml

```
<?php 
/**
 * @copyright Devidas
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 *
 *@var Custom\Modulestock\Block\StockLeft $block
 **/
$productId = $this->getProductId();
$RemainingQty = $block->getRemainingQty($productId);

?>
<p>Qty Available: <?php echo $RemainingQty; ?></p>
```

Override **catalog_product_view.xml** and add below XML

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <container name="productdetailstockleft"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="productdetailstockleft"  after="product.info.price">
                <block class="Custom\Modulestock\Block\StockLeft" name="stockleftproduct" template="Custom_Modulestock::stock_left.phtml" />
            </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Where I should put this? In app/code? Custom\Modulestock\Block\StockLeft.php example: app/code/mymodule/Modulestock/Block/StockLeft.php right?

Comment: yes create new module

Comment: because it's Magento 2 standard.

Comment: don't directly use code in template file

Comment: create the module and add above files in your module and check

Comment: I want display product qty in module (generator PDF catalog) in file: app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml

Comment: So still I want create new module or I can add this to current module Snmportal/Publication ?

Comment: you can directly add in your module

Comment: only  belw xml add in your template layout file <block class="Custom\Modulestock\Block\StockLeft" name="stockleftproduct" template="Custom_Modulestock::stock_left.phtml" />

Comment: can you update your question add template layout then I will update in my ans

Comment: Can you please check my update2 in topic?

Answer (score 1):

You Dont have variable `$productId` in your script.
Try below code.

```
<?php
$_helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$productId = $_product->getId();
$options = $_product->getOptions();
$matrix = $this->getPriceMatrix(2);
/*
* border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
*/
?>
<?php if ($matrix && is_array($matrix)) : ?>
   <h4 class="product name product-item-name">
                                            <?php 
                        $optionText = '';
                        $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mgs_brand');
                        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                           $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getMgsBrand());
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                        <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                        </h4><br />
<table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($matrix as $r => $variant) : ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo ($r % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
            <td style="text-align:left;width:50%">
                <?php $i = 0;
                foreach ($variant['attributes'] as $attribute => $variants) :$i++ ?>
                    <?php if ($i > 1) : ?><br/><?php endif; ?>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $attribute; ?><span>: </span></span>
                    <span class="data"><?php $idx = 0;
                        foreach ($variants as $name => $tmp) : ?><?php echo $idx++ ? ',' : ''; ?><?php echo $name; ?><?php endforeach; ?></span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;width:30%">
                <div class="bl-price-variants"><?php echo $variant['price_formated']; ?></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
echo "Total qty: ";
?>
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager- 
>get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
echo $StockState->getStockQty($productId);
?>
<hr />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/data/generator/price_variants2.phtml on line 3

Comment: @Sylvester , edited my answer. please check now