# Get all visible products whose Quantity greater than 0 in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, out-of-stock

I have written a product collection to get all products whose quantity is greater than 0.

Here is my code for the collection

```
<?php
$websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','sku'));
    $collection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId);
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true); 
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                    $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);                     
                    $collection = $collection
                        ->joinField('qty',
                            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                            'qty',
                            'product_id=entity_id',
                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                            'left'
                        )
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
                        ->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' )                            
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['gt'=>0])
                        ->load();
```

Above Query not loading condfigurable products, bcz all config parent products qty is 0.

How can i get all products which have in_stock here with qty condition. can someone help me out. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this way ..

```
   $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','sku'));
    $collection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId);
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

                    $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);    
                     $collection = $collection
                    ->joinField('qty',
                        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                        'qty',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                    )->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')                 
                        ->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' )                            
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['gt'=>0]);
$procollection = $collection ->create()->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false)->load();
```

Comment: hi @Rakesh, pls update in my code.i am already using $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true); can i set to false?

Comment: @Manjunath ok i have updated my answer here

Comment: some syntax error, pls check once

Comment: @Manjunath i have updated my answer and i have not tested my side

Comment: its not working for me , let me try myself,

Comment: I think u missed the join for qty

Comment: @Manjunath i have quantity field added in filter

Comment: But its not working, try once from you end

Answer (score 0):

This code works for Magento 2.4.6:

```
    /** @var ProductCollection $collection */
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('visibility')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'qty>0'
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use product repository for that.
Use the below code in a block and call it inside the phtml

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
    $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;

    $this->getProductData();
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Block|null
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
protected function getProductData()
{

    $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds())
            ->create(),
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('visibility')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->create(),
    ]);

    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $productItems = $products->getItems();

    return $productItems;
}
```

you can achieve your aim by doing some simple logic to this . you can get the  stock quantity of each product in the $productitem array and take only products having quantity above 0

Refer this question to get the stock count of each product
[How to get stock quantity of each product in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2)

Comment: this will get give all the products data without checking whether the count is greater than 0 or not, Also it loads all not visible individual products also

Comment: I am trying here to get all the visible products whose qty is greater than 0 and In_stock items, with all product types

Comment: It is the basic way to get all the products . Yes it will get the non visible product also. i have updated the ans a bit

Comment: No no, I am trying to filter withing collection only,