# Magento 2 Available Qty Check Before Taking Customers to Payment Gateway

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

When customer tried to place an order , In my website i have only one Qty for each SKU. When two different customers tried to place an order on same time for same SKU one customer got an order number and other customer getting no order number bcz of qty unavailable. I am using magento 2.2.4 version.

How can i check the qty available or not before customer clicks on pay now button in magento page?

I have so many incidents and customer & me spending time to give returns for them as their order is not booked. Again i am loosing money from payment gateway. Is there any solution for this? I tried this observer but not worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">  
 <event name="sales_order_place_before">
    <observer name="my_order_status_check" instance="My\Checkout\Observer\CheckPosBeforePlaceOrder" shared="false" />
</event>
    
</config>
```

I tried below code with

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace My\TestDiscount\Model\Quote;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository as StockItem;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository as Product;

class Discount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    /**
     * Discount calculation object
     *
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator
     */
    protected $calculator;

    /**
     * Core event manager proxy
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;
protected $stockItem;

protected $product;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $validator
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $validator,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $coupon,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $saleRule,
        StockItem $stockItem,
        Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
       
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->calculator = $validator;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->coupon = $coupon;
         $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->saleRule = $saleRule;
    }

    /**
     * Collect address discount amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
  
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $shippingitems = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
 
        if (!count($shippingitems)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();

        try{          
       // $logger->info('Items in cart '.count($quoteitems));
         foreach ($quoteitems as $item) {

            $productId=$this->product->getById($item->getProductId());

            if($item->getProductId()){
    $productQty = $this->stockItem->get($item->getProductId())->getQty();
   }

                $logger->info('stock details'.json_encode($productId->getQty()));

         }
        
        


            

    }catch(Exception $ex){
        $logger->info($ex->getMessage());
    }
            
        return $this;
}

   
}
```

Comment: have you tried `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

Comment: Yes , tried this one as well but it always showing 1 qty if i update in magento2 admin as 0 in inventory.

Comment: I updated my question with code that i am trying with checkout_cart_product_add_after , it is always return stock item as 1.

Comment: How are you updating the stock quantity, I mean when you place an order does your stock get updated from 1 to 0

Comment: Yes..when order is successful qty is updating finely.

Comment: use `getStockQty($productId, $websiteId)` instead of `getQty` try passing website Id with product Id [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2)

Comment: Not worked this as well

Comment: `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface` `$this->stockState->getStockQty($productId)` have you tried this ??