# hello guys please help me out how to get product quantity option on product listing page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, luma-theme, list.phtml

> this is my list.phtml code and look

[image]

> instead I want to display like

[image]

> my code

```
<div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div>
                    <style>
                        .column {
                            float: left;
                            width: 20%;
                            padding: 10px;
                        }

                        .row:after {
                            content: "";
                            display: table;
                            clear: both;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                    ?>
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link"
                           href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                        </a>
                    </strong>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column" style="padding: 1px;border-right: 1px solid #60d0e4;">
                            <?php // Product Image?>
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                               class="product photo product-item-photo"
                               tabindex="-1">
                                <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">

                            <p>Some text..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">

                            <p>Some text..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">

                            <p>Some text..</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">

                            <p>Some text..</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97943/how-to-get-stock-quantity-of-each-product-in-magento-2

Comment: ah sorry! I don't want to get quantity,
I want a button with working and change the price

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the product stock from the product object directly. However, I see you use a `$block` already to retrieve other product information, such as the product image.

Therefore, you can modify the block constructor adding a new dependency in the constructor and creating a new function called `getStockStatus($product)` as follows:

```
// add this dependency in your constructor if already existing
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

// returns product quantity given the product object
public function getStockStatus($product)
{
    return $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
}
```

In your `list.phtml`, you can use

```
$quantity = $block->getStockStatus($product)
```

to get the quantity.

After that, run `bin/magento setup:install`.

Comment: @shaziyali Did it work?

Comment: no, I didn't understand can you explain to me on Instagram as @shaziyali8

Comment: Please upvote the answer.

Comment: ah sorry! I don't want to get quantity,
I want a button with working and change the price